# Android wait for volley to finish and update UI later

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley package to retrieve data from a website(JSON).

Here is my method

```
  private void getEarthquakeList(){
        // ...

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //Earthquake Feeder
        String url ="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.geojson";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response is: ",response);
                        //Parsing Json
                        parseJson(response);
                        final ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                        //Sort the array according to magnitude
                        earthquakeArrayList.sort((a, b) -> Double.compare(b.getTime(), a.getTime()));
                        mAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), earthquakeArrayList);
                        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error",error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

The problem is that right now I am updating the UI inside this method after it returns the response.

These are the lines

```
//Sort the array according to a date
earthquakeArrayList.sort((a, b) -> Double.compare(b.getTime(), a.getTime()));
mAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), earthquakeArrayList);
earthquakeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

While I am running in the MainActivity there is no issue, the user opens the app and gets the list of earthquakes.

The issues start when I want to switch to service where I monitor every couple of minutes or when the website content is changing.
So I want my method without updating the UI in it.
The problem is that If I am not updating the UI inside onResponse, the UI thread continues and results in an empty array.

So this array stay empty `earthquakeArrayList` if I am not doing it inside

```
public void onResponse(String response)
```

Ideas how to separate the two, in one hand running the method and fetching the data and on the other hand the main thread will be able to access the data and not finish executing.
Thanks
EG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended solution right now is to use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata). LiveData works on the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), so you can have any number of observers to the updated data both in the Service and the Activity but they need to be under the same context. These are a bit advanced topics but a good way to decouple your UI with the data layer. You can go through these two links

- [Google IO 2018 session on Livedata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrteWKKVyzI)
- [Medium Article on LiveData](https://medium.com/sears-israel/when-and-why-to-use-android-livedata-93d7dd949138)

Comment: Many thanks, I was not aware of it, I have posted the link to the documents.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata